# Smartway to implement media in Android

Tags: android, performance, collections, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I am working on an Android app, where media(audio/video/images) could be stored either internally/externally. I would be facing the following scenarios

**Case I**
Setting dynamically images from the random value broadcasted by the app. 
Right now, I am managing it as

```
if(rowData.strName.equals("football")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.football);

            }else if(rowData.strName.equals("chess")){
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.chess);
```

**Problem** As of now, I am having few records so managing `else if` loop in not big headache, but later it could turn out to be one.

**Case II**
Downloading  a media from internet, saving it in external storage and loading it on an `imageview` as an when required

**Problem** Incase, the image has already been downloaded(app keeps track of downloaded image), the user  ejects the card, then I plan to use

```
try{
}catch(FileNotFoundException e){

                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_media);//media from the app
}
```

**Case III**
I will be having a `listView` of a category.Each Category contains certain sub-category names,their images(inbuilt & to be downloaded externally) & their description.Each sub-category has sub records with each record having its own one or image(inbuilt & to be downloaded externally),description and media files(both audio and video).

I am confused on what `Collection` class shall I use for this case and how to begin with? For data that is to be retrieved from the server(online), I plan to use `XMLParsing`. Please suggest me the best way to achieve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow! This is really three questions. If only I could get three times the rep :)

**Case I**

Use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store and retrieve stuff. Saves you writing lots of `if/else` statements.

```
Map<String,Integer> drawableMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
drawableMap.put("football", R.drawable.football);
// Then later to retrieve...
imageView.setImageResource(drawableMap.get("football"));
```

**Case II**

OK, this seems fine. Though for most of my image loading I use existing libraries like [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/). These may do what you need, I'm not sure.

**Case III**

I would take an OO approach and model the data appropriately. You don't have to choose "a" `Collection` class to use. Create a `Category` class. Create a `SubCategory` class. Have the `Category` class "have" SubCategories, etc. Take it from there.

XML parsing is fine, I'm not sure what you're expecting to be suggested. You may also like to consider JSON, a popular data format.